# Angular2 *ngIf is not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular

HTML

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/register" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">Register</a>
</li>
```

JS:

```
var auth = this.af.auth.subscribe( (user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User signed in!
        var uid = user;
        var isLoggedIn = true;
        console.log(uid)
        console.log(isLoggedIn);
      } else {
        // User logged out
        console.log("no user")
        var isLoggedIn = false;
        console.log(isLoggedIn);
      }
    });
```

The console is logging the true and false values correctly, so `var isLoggedIn` is correctly changing, but the *ngIf stays hidden no matter what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are redeclaring your `isLoggedIn` in the `if` and `else` block. Instead you should set it like `this.isLoggedin = true` and `this.isLoggedin = false` respectively.

Comment: With this method, I get the error "Property isLoggedIn does not exist on type 'Component'."

Comment: Haven't you declared the variable in the component ?? Before using it in the  template, you have to declare it like this `isLoggedIn: boolean;` in the `component` and set it to a default value to maybe `false` inside the `constructor` like this `this.isLoggedIn  = false`

Comment: Yes, sorry.  That was the missing piece.  Thank you.